# Cron on CentOS not properly executing a php script

Tags: php, linux, unix, cron, centos

I have php scripts I'm trying to execute routinely using cron.

I'm doing this by modifying the crontab file.

crontab contents:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

# For details see man 4 crontabs

# Example of job definition:
# .---------------- minute (0 - 59)
# |  .------------- hour (0 - 23)
# |  |  .---------- day of month (1 - 31)
# |  |  |  .------- month (1 - 12) OR jan,feb,mar,apr ...
# |  |  |  |  .---- day of week (0 - 6) (Sunday=0 or 7) OR sun,mon,tue,wed,thu,fri,sat
# |  |  |  |  |
# *  *  *  *  * user-name command to be executed
*/10 * * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron_update_statuses_one_hour.php
0 */03 * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron_update_statuses_three_hour.php
0 */08 * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron_update_statuses_eight_hour.php
0 */16 * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron_update_statuses_sixteen_hour.php
0 0 * * * root /usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron_update_statuses_one_day.php
```

cron log:

```
Jul 13 00:10:01 s1 CROND[2944]: (root) CMD (cd /var/www/html/ /usr/bin/php             cron_update_statuses_one_hour.php)
Jul 13 00:12:01 s1 crond[2124]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jul 13 01:00:01 s1 CROND[2977]: (root) CMD (/usr/sbin/raid-check)
Jul 13 01:01:01 s1 CROND[2992]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 13 01:01:01 s1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[2992]: starting 0anacron
Jul 13 01:01:01 s1 anacron[3001]: Anacron started on 2014-07-13
Jul 13 01:01:01 s1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3003]: finished 0anacron
Jul 13 01:01:01 s1 anacron[3001]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Jul 13 01:01:01 s1 anacron[3001]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jul 13 01:07:01 s1 crond[2124]: (*system*) RELOAD (/etc/crontab)
Jul 13 01:10:01 s1 CROND[3022]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php     /var/www/html/cron_update_statuses_one_hour.php)
Jul 13 02:01:01 s1 CROND[3059]: (root) CMD (run-parts /etc/cron.hourly)
Jul 13 02:01:01 s1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3059]: starting 0anacron
Jul 13 02:01:01 s1 anacron[3068]: Anacron started on 2014-07-13
Jul 13 02:01:01 s1 anacron[3068]: Jobs will be executed sequentially
Jul 13 02:01:01 s1 anacron[3068]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jul 13 02:01:01 s1 run-parts(/etc/cron.hourly)[3070]: finished 0anacron
Jul 13 02:10:01 s1 CROND[3072]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php /var/www/html/cron_update_statuses_one_hour.php)
```

100% sure that php location is correct; 100% sure that cron service is running; 100% sure that the location of my scripts are correct

Also, yes I realize that my first entry is set to run that command every 10 minutes, I did this only for debugging purposes, please pretend its set to run it every hour

Please help *nix experts Big Grin | :-D !

Thank you

Comment: Generally the first thing to check with cron problems is all of your environment variables.  crond does NOT login as the user, so .profile,  and so on,  may not have been executed.  Execute set >/tmp/set.1 from the command line.  Run the command set > /tmp/set.2 as a cron job.   Compare the two files

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what your PHP scripts are supposed to do, so I can only assume you've made the proper checks as to whether they working properly.

Have you tried running the scripts from the command line directly?

$ php /var/www/html/cron_update_statuses_one_hour.php

Try adding /var/www/html to your PATH.

Also check the PHP log and see if any errors are showing up there.

Comment: Thank you - it was just an error in the syntax of the cron command